# How to change Adjust Scrollback - Konsole, via Bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

with
`neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'`
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

Question:
via Bash commands ...
how to change Adjust Scrollback - Konsole
from Fixed size = `1000` Lines
__to Fixed size = `9999` Lines or more ?

.

How to show Adjust Scrollback value?

- Open Terminal (Ctrl Alt T) = bash - Konsole <#>
- mouse right click
- Adjust Scrollback
- Fixed size = `1000` Lines

What are the Bash commands to change above from
`1000` Lines to
`9999` Lines?

--